# Using ArcPy to Switch Layout Templates?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, layouts, template

Using ArcMap 10.1, since there is not a way to control portrait or landscape of the layout view through python, is there a way to switch layout templates without opening a new mxd through python?

Since there is a change layout template button it would be nice to have a python function to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

You could request this as an [ArcGIS Idea](http://ideas.arcgis.com) but so far, at least for me, requirements like this have been easy to meet by just opening a new MapDocument object so I suspect it would not attract a lot of votes.

For example, when [Selecting predefined ArcMap template using ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/178011/selecting-predefined-arcmap-template-using-arcpy) means a "predefined template" to be an MXD located in a Map template folder inside an ArcGIS installation directory, it should just need:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"Current")
```

(although there is no need for the `r` before "Current" above)

to be replaced with:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"<path>\<template>.mxd")
```

Comment: I took "predefined template" to mean a layout template you'd typically use the "Change Layout" button on that Layout toolbar in ArcMap.  Changing the MapDocument here wouldn't give the same result.

Comment: @Midavalo I've not tested recently but I think it would at any version from 10.0 onwards i.e. since *.mxt files ceased to be used to define map templates.

Comment: Predefined templates now use MXD instead of MXT, however the button still exists and functions the same way "Change Layout - Change the Layout by selecting a predefined template" is the tooltip text. Using arcpy.mapping.MapDocument would just make arcpy run on a completely different MXD rather than use one MXD as a template for the CURRENT.

Comment: @Midavalo There's no ArcPy method to do precisely that, and ArcPy is primarily designed for map automation with less emphasis on using it interactively within ArcMap.  I think that is a pity sometimes, but I think it also means that the way I have suggested may be the asker's best option.