# Selecting predefined ArcMap template using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, layouts, element

i have managed to create script for search cursor which will replace the text element in one of the template from help provided from my previous question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/172544/replacing-text-element-from-feature-class-value-using-arcpy I would like to know how i can specify the predefined template in the script below so that the script automatically load the template..

Currently i am change the template manually. the template is located in my Map template folder inside Arcgis installation directory.

note: this script is used in creating a map printout which also has select by attribute > zoom to selected feature, change view to layout view > update text element > print.

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"Current")
table = r"C:\Users\name\Documents\ArcGIS\DATA.gdb\\Layer" # lyr from which data will be pulled
value = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)# enter UNIQUE_REC from layer
query = "\"UNIQUE_REC\" = %s" % (value) # string conversion via str() prior to formatting
theseRows = arcpy.SearchCursor(table, query)

for row in theseRows:
if theseRows:
    print(row.getValue("LOT"))
else:
       print "CORRECT UNIQUE_REC"
for elm in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT"):
   if elm.text == "text7":
     elm.text = (row.getValue("LOT"))  
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
del mxd
```